# Error message not shown when I click on a link in favorites

Tags: c#

When I click on a certain website in my favorites tab that is not used for work I have to get an error message.

Here is the code where I am trying to disable the website `www.nu.nl` `www.buienradar.nl` and `www.weeronline.nl`

```
private void lbFavo_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  if (lbFavo.SelectedItem != "www.nu.nl" || 
      lbFavo.SelectedItem != "www.weeronline.nl" || 
      lbFavo.SelectedItem != "www.buienradar.nl")
    {
      webBrowser.Navigate(lbFavo.SelectedItem.ToString());
      tabWeb.TabPages[0].Text = lbFavo.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }

    if (cbGeschiedenis.Items.IndexOf(lbFavo.SelectedItem.ToString()) ==
         cbGeschiedenis.SelectedIndex)
    {
      webBrowser.Navigate(lbFavo.SelectedItem.ToString());
      cbGeschiedenis.Items.Add(lbFavo.SelectedItem.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
      ErrorMelding.SetError(txtURL,
                            "U moet zich bezig houden met werk en niet met prive!!");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: || should be &&

Comment: you have an extra `}` in your example. This wont even compile.

Comment: Read up on the [|| operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-or-operator)

Comment: `if( !a || !b )` will always be true in this case. If a is true, then b is not, if b is true, then a is not, if both a and b are false , then the whole expression is true and both cannot be true in your case.

Comment: Also, it would probably be preferable to use a (black-)list and check if SelectedItem's value is contained in it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `&&` *([AND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-and-operator))* operator in this situation not `||` *([OR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-or-operator))*

```
  private void lbFavo_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
       //using && instead of || here. You want to evaluate all strings before you navigate to the site.
       if (lbFavo.SelectedItem != "www.nu.nl" && lbFavo.SelectedItem != "www.weeronline.nl" && lbFavo.SelectedItem != "www.buienradar.nl")
       {
          webBrowser.Navigate(lbFavo.SelectedItem.ToString());
          tabWeb.TabPages[0].Text = lbFavo.SelectedItem.ToString();
       }
       if (cbGeschiedenis.Items.IndexOf(lbFavo.SelectedItem.ToString()) == cbGeschiedenis.SelectedIndex)
       {
          webBrowser.Navigate(lbFavo.SelectedItem.ToString());
          cbGeschiedenis.Items.Add(lbFavo.SelectedItem.ToString());
       }
       else
       {
          ErrorMelding.SetError(txtURL, "U moet zich bezig houden met werk en niet met prive!!");
       }
  }
```

---

### Alternatively

You could tidy up your first `if` condition using a [switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch) statement

```
  private void lbFavo_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
       switch( lbFavo.SelectedItem )
       {
          //useful for tidiness sake if you want to disable a lot of "URL's"
          case "www.nu.nl":
          case "www.weeronline.nl":
          case "www.buienradar.nl":
                //output error message, or just do nothing
                break;
          default: 
               webBrowser.Navigate(lbFavo.SelectedItem.ToString());
               tabWeb.TabPages[0].Text = lbFavo.SelectedItem.ToString();
               break;
       }

       if (cbGeschiedenis.Items.IndexOf(lbFavo.SelectedItem.ToString()) == cbGeschiedenis.SelectedIndex)
       {
          webBrowser.Navigate(lbFavo.SelectedItem.ToString());
          cbGeschiedenis.Items.Add(lbFavo.SelectedItem.ToString());
       }
       else
       {
          ErrorMelding.SetError(txtURL, "U moet zich bezig houden met werk en niet met prive!!");
       }
  }
```

Comment: Switch not really an improvement it is. Use list or use list not, there is no try. ;) May the 4th be with you!

Comment: I know ;) I agree a list would be much more useful, the switch statement was more for formatting OP's current code but reformatting would be better.

Answer (score 0):

If you have in your class

```
private List<string> blacklist = new List<string>() {
    "www.nu.nl",
    "www.weeronline.nl",
    "www.buienradar.nl"
};
```

you can do

```
private void lbFavo_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if( !blacklist.Contains(lbFavo.SelectedItem) )
    {
         // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

This

```
if (lbFavo.SelectedItem != "www.nu.nl" || 
  lbFavo.SelectedItem != "www.weeronline.nl" || 
  lbFavo.SelectedItem != "www.buienradar.nl")
```

will always be true, because `lbFavo.SelectedItem` cannot be all three values at once.